# resizing window remain buttons in same position inside div

Tags: html, css

How can I manage resizing of window on my computer, so they can keep their position with any size of window? I dont want to use bootstrap

```
<div class="list-group navbar" >
 <div class = "row" style = "padding:0px; margin: 0px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:2px">
 <div>
   <!--<a class="navi-background navi-text navi-style" onclick="openParamFrame();"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw navi-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Settings"></i></a>-->
  <a href = "#" style = "outline:none;" onclick="openFrame();"><img src = "images/icons/settings_icon_white.png" style = "max-width:50px;"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Settings"></a>
    </div>
 <div>
<a href = "#" style = "outline:none;"onclick="send_command('reset', '');"><img src = "images/icons/refresh-icon.png" style = "max-width:50px;"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Reset"></a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your code looks like, but try adding this to whatever you want to stay in the same place:

```
.yourClass {
    position:fixed;
}
```

If you post your code I could be able to help you a little more.

**EDIT**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k0naLryL/) is a fiddle, maybe also set the width of your navigation bar as well as the position to fixed, and it might work, good luck! Tell me if it doesn't work though :)

Comment: i tried with fixed position, didnt work, maybe I did It in wrong place ?

Comment: Maybe, could you please create a working fiddle of what you already have so I can maybe play around with the code myself and see if I can fix it? If you don't know how just post the html and css used in the original question, thank you.

Comment: thank You so much, but I would really like to do it myself, can You maybe give me some suggestions what can be solution, position:fixed is one of them, do You have any other idea ? and I will try to do it myself :)

Comment: Okay so tell me exactly, in plentiful detail, what you want to do, and I will try to help you as much as possible. :)

Comment: Design is already having everything that I want, and buttons are in row next to each, everything is fine. Problem is when I am resizing window, when it becomes smaller buttons align vertically, they dont stay horizontal as they do when the window is full size

Comment: I think I may know why it didn't work before... check my updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property

```
width : auto;
```

So that they won't wrap until the width becomes too small.

Comment: Can you post your entire code please? Your code is missing div for now. What behavior would you like to implement ? Images next to another, or in a column?

Comment: its edited :) everything works good, buttons are next to each other in row, but I want them to remain in same position on side_bar when I am resizing window, but they change from row position to column position ;(

Comment: Thank you, for now by copying and pasting your code I got this : https://jsfiddle.net/x1L3et0g/  , Button are in column even if the window is wide..

Comment: ah, sorry, its because there is css class i forgot to paste : a:link
{
        float:left;
        display:inline;
        margin:5px;
}